# Use multiples of an index to keep or replace values in a vector

Tags: r, vector, sequence

"Mean" is a 1x756 numeric vector

This is the sequence (numeric vector) I want to write:

```
L <- c(rep(0, 251), Mean[252],
       rep(0, 251), Mean[252*2],
       rep(0, 251), Mean[252*3])
```

That is, at multiples of 252, I want to keep the original values. Other indexes should be replaced with zero.

Is there a smarter way I could write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%%` (modulo) on a sequence along your vector, with the (first) index of replacement as divisor. Replace values where the result of the division is zero*.

```
Mean[seq_along(Mean) %% 252 != 0] <- 0
```

Smaller example, where also the hardcoding of the first index is avoided:

```
set.seed(2)
x <- sample(12)

x[seq_along(x) %% (length(x) / 3) != 0] <- 0
x
# [1]  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  5  0  0  0 10
```

---

*Thanks to @snoram for suggesting a more straight-forward alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, we could split into groups and then do the concatenation

```
i1 <- rep(1:3, each = 252) 
i2 <- rep(1:3, each = 251)
unlist(Map(c, split(rep(0, 753), i2), split(Mean * i1, i1)), use.names = FALSE)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
Mean <- rnorm(756)
```